# getting 2 comboboxes working from QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: python, database, combobox, pyqt

Please be kind.  This is my first question.  I have included a minimum listing that illustrates the problem.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, uic, QtSql
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
qtCreatorFile = "QuotesGui.ui" 

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class QuotesUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, model):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi(qtCreatorFile,self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = model # View owns the model    


        self.tableView.setModel(self.model._formModel)

        self.setWidgetMapping() # Map model to view widgets

        authorSRD = QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.authorComboBox)
        self.authorComboBox.setModel(self.model._authorModel)
        self.authorComboBox.setItemDelegate(authorSRD)
        self.authorComboBox.setModelColumn(
        self.model._formModel.fieldIndex("authorName"))

        citationSRD = QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.citationComboBox)
        self.citationComboBox.setModel(self.model._citationModel)
        self.citationComboBox.setItemDelegate(citationSRD)
        self.citationComboBox.setModelColumn(
        self.model._formModel.fieldIndex("citationText"))

        self.mainMapper.toFirst()
        self._updateButtons(0) # To disable the previous button at start up
        self.saveBtn.setEnabled(False) # Since we can't edit, we can't save


        self._connectSignals(self.model)



    def setWidgetMapping(self):
        self.mainMapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mainMapper.setModel(self.model._formModel)
        self.mainMapper.setItemDelegate(QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(self))
        self.mainMapper.addMapping(self.authorComboBox,
            self.model._formModel.fieldIndex("authorName"))
        self.mainMapper.addMapping(self.citationComboBox,
            self.model._formModel.fieldIndex("citationText"))
        self.mainMapper.addMapping(self.quoteText,
            self.model._formModel.fieldIndex("quoteText"))


    def _connectSignals(self, model):
        self.lastBtn.clicked.connect(self.mainMapper.toLast)
        self.nextBtn.clicked.connect(self.mainMapper.toNext)
        self.prevBtn.clicked.connect(self.mainMapper.toPrevious)
        self.firstBtn.clicked.connect(self.mainMapper.toFirst)
        self.mainMapper.currentIndexChanged.connect(
            self._updateButtons)




    def _updateButtons(self, row):
        self.firstBtn.setEnabled(row > 0)
        self.prevBtn.setEnabled(row > 0)
        self.nextBtn.setEnabled(row < self.model._formModel.rowCount() - 1)
        self.lastBtn.setEnabled(row < self.model._formModel.rowCount() - 1)


class QuoteModel():
    def __init__(self, data):
        # Make a database connection
        self.db = self.createConnection(data)

        # set models
        self._setFormModel()
        self._setAuthorComboTableLink()
        self._setCitationComboTableLink()   

        # Connect signals
        self._connectSignals()

    # Define a model for the form
    def _setFormModel(self):
        self._formModel = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel(
            parent = None, db = self.db)
        self._formModel.setEditStrategy(
            QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self._formModel.setTable("Quote")
        authorIdx = self._formModel.fieldIndex("authorId")
        citationIdx = self._formModel.fieldIndex("citationId")
        self._formModel.setJoinMode(1) # Left Join
        self._formModel.setRelation(authorIdx, QtSql.QSqlRelation(
            "Author", "authorId", "authorName"))
        self._formModel.setRelation(citationIdx, QtSql.QSqlRelation(
            "Citation", "citationId", "citationText"))
        self._formModel.select()


     # Define models and link tables for the two comboboxes
     def _setAuthorComboTableLink(self):
        self._authorModel = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(
            parent = None, db =   self.db)
        self._authorModel.setTable("Author")
        self._authorModel.setEditStrategy(
            QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self._authorModel.select()
        self._authorModel.sort(1,Qt.AscendingOrder) 

    def _setCitationComboTableLink(self):
        self._citationModel = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(
            parent = None, db = self.db)
        self._citationModel.setTable("Citation")
        self._citationModel.setEditStrategy(
            QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self._citationModel.select()
        self._citationModel.sort(1,Qt.AscendingOrder)   

    def _newData(self):
        print('in _newData')

    def _connectSignals(self):
        self._authorModel.rowsInserted.connect(self._newData)


#######################################################     
    # A function to connect to a named database
    def createConnection(self,dbfile):
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName(dbfile)
        db.open()

        if not db.open():
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(
            None, QtWidgets.qApp.tr("Cannot open database"),
            QtWidgets.qApp.tr("Unable to establish a database   connection.\n"),
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
            )
            return False

        return db

dbFile = "Quotations.db"

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    m = QuoteModel(dbFile)

    w = QuotesUI(m)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Still requires the upload of a 8kb .ui file and a 70kb sample database to run.  So far I haven't been able to figure out how to do that....

When this is run, incorporating the rest of the necessary code, the author combobox works as expected, i.e.: the dropdown shows all the values in the author table and when I step the the records in the model, the correct author is displayed in the combobox.

The citation combobox does NOT function.  As written here it neither shows values from the citation table, nor is it connected to the quotes table.  Basically it shows nothing.

I think I need, somehow, a second delegate on the model.  But I don't know how.

Any ideas how to get this functioning??

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: If I change this line:  self.citationComboBox.setModelColumn(
        self.model._formModel.fieldIndex("citationText")) to self.citationComboBox.setModelColumn(
        self.model._formModel.fieldIndex("authorName")) the combobox is disconnect from the Quote table, but shows all the choices from the Citation table.

Comment: If I change this line: self.citationComboBox.setModel(self.model._citationModel) to self.citationComboBox.setModel(self.model._formModel) the combobox is connected to the Quote table and the dropdown shows only the Citation records as they are attached to the Quote table.  This suggests to me that there is a problem with the delegate on the model, that there should be separate delegates for the authorCombo and the citationCombo.  I don't know how to do that.  Can you help??

Answer (score 0):

To make this work I had to change:

```
self.authorComboBox.setModel(self.model._authorModel)
```

to:

```
authorRel = self.model._formModel.relationModel(self.model.authorIdx)
self.authorComboBox.setModel(authorRel)
```

The QSqlRelationalTableModel has a virtual function "relationModel" that returns a QSqlTableModel.  When you use this model as the model for the QComboBox, everything works.